# Is it possible to draw a line chart using birt framework?

Tags: java, eclipse, birt, rcp

I would like to create a line chart in my rcp application.is it possible to plot a line chart dynamically using birt.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Birt supports various kinds of charts including a simple line chart.

On the [demo-page](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/demos/) look at the section "Combination Chart". There is a linked [Video-Tutorial](http://demo.actuate.com/demos/combochart/combinationchart.html) on how to add the data to a chart in birt.